# Python yelp scraper

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to parse different names and phone numbers of various restaurant names from yelp.com. The scraper is doing its job just fine. The most important feature of this scraper is that it can handle pagination on the fly (if there is any) no matter how many pages it traverses. I tried to create it following the guidelines of OOP. However, I suppose there are still some options to make it better, as in isolating the `while True` loop by storing it in another function.

This is the script:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class YelpScraper:
    link = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc={}&find_loc={}&start={}'

    def __init__(self, name, location, num="0"):
        self.name = quote_plus(name)
        self.location = quote_plus(location)
        self.num = quote_plus(num)
        self.base_url = self.link.format(self.name,self.location,self.num)
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def get_info(self):
        s = self.session
        s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

        while True:
            res = s.get(self.base_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
            for items in soup.select("div.biz-listing-large"):
                name = items.select_one(".biz-name span").get_text(strip=True)
                try:
                    phone = items.select_one("span.biz-phone").get_text(strip=True)
                except AttributeError: phone = ""
                print("Name: {}\nPhone: {}\n".format(name,phone))

            link = soup.select_one(".pagination-links .next")
            if not link:break
            self.base_url = "https://www.yelp.com" + link.get("href")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape = YelpScraper("Restaurants","San Francisco, CA")
    scrape.get_info()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to quote parameters yourself, `requests` can [do it for you](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls);
2. [You don't need a class](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/stop-writing-classes.html) for that, a simple function will suffice; I’d extract retrieving content from a URL as another function though;
3. Separate logic from presentation: have your function `return` a list of name/phone pairs and have the calling code responsible of printing it. Better, turn the function into [a generator and `yield` the pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/5069029) as you go;
4. There is no need to decode the content before parsing it: the `lxml` parser work best with a sequence of bytes as it can inspect the `<head>` to use the appropriate encoding.

Proposed improvements:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def url_fetcher(session, route, base_url='https://www.yelp.com', **kwargs):
    params = kwargs if kwargs else None

    return session.get(base_url + route, params=params)


def yelp_scraper(name, location, num=0):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    response = url_fetcher(session, '/search', find_desc=name, find_loc=location, start=num)
    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        for items in soup.select('div.biz-listing-large'):
            name = items.select_one('.biz-name span').get_text(strip=True)
            try:
                phone = items.select_one('span.biz-phone').get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                phone = ''
            yield name, phone

        link = soup.select_one('.pagination-links .next')
        if not link:
            break
        response = url_fetcher(session, link.get('href'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for name, phone in yelp_scraper('Restaurants', 'San Francisco, CA'):
        print('Name:', name)
        print('Phone:', phone)
        print()
```

Comment: I did not know that the `lxml` parser can directly take the `response.content` and does not need `response.text`!

Comment: @Graipher reading from the docs, there might even be a possibility that the raw response object can be used instead: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function

Comment: Thanks @Mathias Ettinger for showing a new way of doing things. My intention was to do the same using class as I'm a new to OOP. If it were not for class I could have done the same using a single function. Povided +1. Thanks.